# Long to byte array converter doesn't work in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, byte, long-integer

I made a converter which is supposed to work, and works in some cases, but in this case it doesn't work.

The problem is that when `cout`ing the `unsigned char`s generated, one time everything is 255, another time 0. What's wrong with this code??

Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void longToBytes(long num, unsigned char arr[4])
{
    arr[0]= (int)((num >> 24) & 0xFF);
    arr[1]= (int)((num >> 16) & 0xFF);
    arr[2]= (int)((num >> 8) & 0xFF);
    arr[3]= (int)( num & 0xFF);
}

long bytesToLong(unsigned char arr[4])
{
    return ((arr[0] << 24) + (arr[1] << 16) + (arr[2] << 8) + arr[3]);
}

void writelongs(long mas[], int howMany)
{
    for(int i=0; i<howMany; i++)
    {
        unsigned char bytes[4];

        cout<<mas[i]<<endl;

        longToBytes(mas[i], bytes);

        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
        {
            cout<<(int)bytes[i]; //Problem here.
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long aray[2]={-118, 1034};

    writelongs(aray,2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume you wanted to print `bytes[j]`, not `bytes[i]`, right?

Comment: I'd say that's the problem he's printing bytes[i] instead of bytes[j]

Comment: Is it really important to say "which is supposed to work"? Has anyone ever tried to build something that isn't supposed to work?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes, when producing an MCVE ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
{
    cout<<(int)bytes[i]; // Problem here.
}
```

You used the index i instead of j.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++)
{
    cout << (int)bytes[j]; // Problem solved.
}
```

Comment: And this is why you should *always* give your variables descriptive names, even if they're trivial loop counters. Not to mention the fact that `i` in this case is *not* a trivial loop counter, as the loop itself is not trivial.

Comment: Wow, so lame mistake :D